# webrtc and canvas: why does it always display as 300px *150px

Tags: canvas, html5-canvas, webrtc

I am using a simple snapshot snippet for webrtc

```
function snap() {
    var snapshot = document.getElementById("snapshot"),
         video = document.querySelector("video");
    snapshot.getContext("2d").drawImage(video, 0, 0, snapshot.width, snapshot.height);
    console.log(snapshot.toDataURL("image/png"));
}
```

From: https://lincolnloop.com/blog/what-webrtc/

My problem is that the snpashot is always 300x*150px size !

How can I make it bigger ?

Answer (score 1):

The default size of a HTML canvas is 300px x 150px.

The snapshot can only fill the size of the canvas, no matter what parameter size you place in the drawImage function. If you set the canvas to a different size, then this code will fill that space (as long as aspect ratios are the same). Try this canvas size for example:

```
<canvas id="snapshot" style="width:500px; height:250px;"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Resize the canvas element itself:**

```
// for example, resize the canvas element to 640x480
snapshot.width=640;
snapshot.height=480;
```